# I have an assignment to write odd number

Tags: python, loops, input

I wanted to print odd numbers as many as input.

Example: input=7
Output: 1,3,5,7,9,11,13

This is what i wrote

---

```
a=int(input("input how many odd numbers to print: "))
for i in range(a):
    if(i%2==1):
        print(i)
```

---

Yes, the output is obviously
1
3
5

And i tried this too

---

```
a=int(input("input ho many odd numbers to print: "))
i=1
while(i<=a):
    if(i%2==1):
        print(i)
```

---

The output is infinite loop printing the input number

Comment: can you fix your fomat while you are at it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this, and this forum. I need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a=int(input("input how many odd numbers to print: "))
for i in range(1,a*2,2):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Omg thanks, i missed those range logic, god it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a `while` loop

```
i = 1
counter = 0
while counter < a:
    if i % 2 == 1:
         print(i)
         counter += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, i love this idea of using counter.

Answer (score -2):

In the `while-loop`, the variable `i` never changes, so you're just reprinting the same number over and over again. Try this:

```
while(i<=a):
    if(i%2==1):
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, as it won't print ALL the numbers that he wants

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses, i appreciate all your answer. It's helpful